# Portrait orientation only for iPad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, orientation, portrait

According to apple my application has to be able to run in both portrait modes.  How do I accomplish this with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just return YES no matter what the interface orientation is. This will allow the system autorotate to the upside-down orientation.

If you don't want to support the landscape orientations, then return:

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
```

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to play in landscape mode, it doesn't work right.  I just want the two portrait modes

Answer (score 6):

This code allows any orientation except landscape:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return (orientation != UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) &&
           (orientation != UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Submitted app was rejected for the above reason. App used only  portrait(Home Button Down) orientation.

" app does not comply with the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, app only supported the bottom-up variant of the portrait orientation, but not the top-up variant.

While supporting both variants of both orientations, each with unique launch images, provides the best user experience and is recommended, we understand there are certain applications that must run in the portrait orientation only. In this case, it would be appropriate to support both variants of that orientation in your application, e.g., Home button up and down."

To solve.
1)

```
 `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

2) Open info.plist add a new string `UILaunchImageFile & insert value as Default-Portrait.png`

3) Change Default.png to Default-Portrait.png & Duplicate the file to rename Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png(Rotate this one with 180 degree)

This enables up & down portrait with respective launch images.

make sure you use UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation) in all view-controllers inside the app, if required so . also do a clean before run.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.